# AWS: Error when calling getCredentialsForIdentity()

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am trying to get a login procedure to work in AWS by following the Enhanced Authflow for Developer Authentication mentioned in the [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html).

The code in both client and server are using JavaScript, and I'm using Node.js on the server-side.

I have managed to get the OpenId token back to the client but when I try to exchange it for credentials by calling `getCredentialsForIdentity()`, the client receives this error:

> NotAuthorizedException: Access to Identity 'eu-west-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' is forbidden.

Also on the server-side when I print the variable holding my `AWS.CognitoIdentity` object and check the property `cognitoidentity.config.credentialProvider` all I get is:

```
{"providers":[null,null,null,null]}
```

It feels like the named custom developer provider I have associated with my identity pool should be in there but I seem to not be able to get it there.

Any thoughts on where I might have gone wrong?

Comment: do you have sufficient IAM rights in AWS to call getCredentialsForIdentity ?

Comment: I think so but I am not  entirely sure. How can I verify that?

Comment: the easiest test is to temporary grant admin rights and test again. Just to be sure

Comment: This is what I try to do now. I know That I shouldn't use hardcoded account keys in client code but this is for testing as you suggested. I still get the same error though.

Comment: `function GetCredentialsForIdentity(data) {
    var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity({
        accessKeyId: myObject.AWS_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: myObject.AWS_ACCOUNT_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        region: myObject.AWS_REGION
    });

    var params = {
        IdentityId: data.IdentityId
    };
    cognitoidentity.getCredentialsForIdentity(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        }
        else {
            if (data) {
                console.log("success: " + data);
            }
        }
    });
}`

Comment: I appearently have not got a hang of the formating yet. Sorry.

Comment: the doc says "In order for Amazon Cognito to call AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity on your behalf, your identity pool must have IAM roles associated with it", so maybe you should also grant rights to the IAM role attached to your identity pool?

Answer (score 1):

That error is usually thrown when you try to get access to an authenticated id without providing any of the tokens linked to that identity. If it's an authenticated identity, make sure you are giving a token for it.